# Objects in Viewport go haywire and showing weird things

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, uv, 3d-view

I've started learning blender recently. Currently, I'm doing the apple tutorial by CGBoost.

In the viewport, the objects go out of control and showing weird thins, as shown below.
[image]

However, when I render the scene with the cycles engine the result is normal:

[image]

This problem occurred when I've cut an apple in two and added a new texture to the top part.

I was wondering maybe it's a caching problem which I have to clear or maybe it's a bug?

Please help.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue, the scene is properly displayed in viewport as well as render on my side. I could be caching issue on the cloth simulation. so try baking.

Comment: I found out particles (water drops on the apples) are causing the problem, because when I turn the particle off in the viewport it gets normal.