# Model from one machine goes haywire in another

Tags: modeling, mesh

I uploaded a few .blend files to Google Drive last year. I downloaded them today and loaded them in another machine. Both machines use 2.82a.

For example, the tires, which are a circle with Mirror and SubSurf modifiers seem like they have vertices in some far off location. This is happening with other files as well.

Can someone help me with this?

I see someone had a similar problem but didn't get a solution

[Objects in Viewport go haywire and showing weird things](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190542/objects-in-viewport-go-haywire-and-showing-weird-things)

[image]

Comment: Do some objects use a displace modifier ? Make sure there is no missing file by going File > External Data > Report missing files

Comment: @Gorgious the only files missing are the reference images. There's no displace mod. I added the blend file

Comment: looks ok on 2.92

Comment: @Mobin Yes, it does. That's weird, because it was made in 282a

Comment: please provide blend file